# How do I backup MMS messages in my Sony Ericsson K608i to my PC?

Tags: backup, mobile-phone

I can't find any software that does it.  I don't want to manually save the images/videos/audio for each MMS I have.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [floAt's Mobile Agent](http://fma.sourceforge.net/index2.htm). It has a lot of useful features for Sony Ericsson phones and I know it can be used to backup SMS messages, contacts, settings. Maybe it can also save MMS messages.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet.  Will do, when I find the time.

Answer (score 2):

[MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/) is another good alternative. MyPhoneExplorer can also sync your contacts with Google contacts, can be very handy when moving from one phone to another

Comment: I already use MyPhoneExplorer to backup up everything else -- except MMS.